# Structure assignment with pointer

Tags: c

I'm having trouble what this line of code does:

```
struct node* node = (struct node*)
```

Code is used in this context:

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node* newNode(int key)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)
    malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key   = key;
    node->left   = NULL;
    node->right  = NULL;
    node->height = 1;  // new node is initially added at leaf
    return(node);
}
```

And why is the pointer placed after the identifier?

Comment: notice that line has no semicolon at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's tricky

```
struct node* node = (struct node*)
malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

can be rewrited as

```
struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

And it is just a type conversion.

However, in C there is no necessary for explicit cast from `void*` (return type of `malloc`) and vice-versa unlike to C++. The compiler does this work.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the whole line - the expression continues on the next line until the semicolon:

```
struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

This is the normal dynamic allocation with a cast, which is entirely unnecessary in C. The line should look like this:

```
struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: Back to front - the cast is necessary in C++, but entirely unnecessary (and arguably harmful) in C.

Comment: @NigelHarper This is fixed - I meant to write it the other way around. I don't think it's too harmful, though, because the cast and the pointer type on the left must match anyway. I view it as a way to avoid unnecessary repetition.

Comment: Even better to write `struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));`

Answer (score 0):

You have the code wrapped to the next line.

```
struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```